# SharePoint workflow utility

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a utility or set of Powershell scripts available for free (or not) that can inspect a SharePoint workflow instance?  I'm struggling with a very difficult issue where a SharePoint workflow appears to be stuck and the associated task is not being created.

Inspection of logs has turned up nothing.